# Randomised Backgrounds with background overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to randomise my website background with a overlay but I'm having problems getting randomised backgrounds to show.

This is what I'm working with

.css / .php

```css
#intro {
  background:
          /* top, transparent black gradient */ 
      linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)

 ),
 /* bottom, image */
        
        url(/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>);
  background-size: 100% auto, cover;
  background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
  background-position: top left, bottom center;
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;


 }
```

```html
<?php
  $bg = array('bg-01.png', 'bg-02.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

I've checked the file names for bg-01.png, bg-02.jpg and are correct. Help would be greatly appreciated on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does the **CSS** file have a **.php** extension?  As in *style.css.php*?

Comment: When do the backgrounds change? On page loading? User clicks a button? Day to day basis? There's an event if there is change.

Comment: on page loading so every time you load the website it should show a different background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep Css and php code in one file and first load php code after css

```
<?php
      $bg = array('bg-01.png', 'bg-02.jpg' ); // array of filenames

      $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
      $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was  chosen
?>

<style> 
     #intro {
        background:
          /* top, transparent black gradient */ 
      linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)

 ),
 /* bottom, image */

        url(/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>);
        background-size: 100% auto, cover;
        background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
        background-position: top left, bottom center;
        background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;


    }

 </style>
```

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

Why would you wanna use php for that anyway? Very nasty way of coding when combining css and php.

javascript way more clean for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bgList = ['bg-01.png', 'bg-02.png'];
    var bg = bgList[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgList.length)];

    $('#intro').css('background', bg);

    var path = '/images/';
    $('#intro').css('background', path+bg);
}); 
</script>
```